# Dúvida com serviço rest e com verbo put

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api

Eu preciso apenas fazer uma atualização em dois campos da minha model. No get eu passo um DTO para o meu App. A pergunta é: Quando eu for fazer o meu update(verbo put) eu preciso carregar todas as propriedade ou apenas a que eu vou atualizar? Tipo assim:

```
[Route("atualiza/{id}")]
        public void AtualizaLiberacao(LiberacaoDTO libera,int id)
        {
            var lista = contexto.Liberacoes
                .Where(l => l.IdOrcamento == id)
                .Select(s =>
                {
                    s.AutorizouReceberAtrazado = float.Parse(libera.AutorizouReceberAtrazado),
                    s.FlagLiberacao = 0
                });
        }
```

Somente esses campos receberão novos valores, demais não. E como eu passo o texto que será atualizado? O id ok, mas o texto. Coloquei um LiberacaoDTO apenas como exemplo, mas posso passar o texto como string, essa é a minha dúvida. No lugar do objeto posso passar o texto(string) a ser modificado. Tudo isso é apenas ilustrativo. Tem como passar dois parâmetros pela URL, ao invés de apenas o id?

Meu serviço:

```
[AcceptVerbs("Put")]
 public void putItensLiberacao(int id, [FromBody]string value)
 {

 }
```

**EDIT1**

```
[Route("atualiza/{id}")]
        public void AtualizaLiberacao(LiberacaoDTO libera)
        {
                contexto.Liberacoes
                .Where(l => l.IdOrcamento == libera.IdOrcamento)
                .Select(s =>
                {
                    s.AutorizouReceberAtrazado = libera.AutorizouReceberAtrazado;
                    s.FlagLiberacao = libera.FlagLiberacao;
                });
        }
```

A forma acima é a correta? E como fica a rota com o id? Para que vai servi ele?

Acho que é isso:

```
[Route("atualiza/{id}/{value}")]
    public void AtualizaLiberacao(int id, string value)
    {
        var lista = contexto.Liberacoes
                    .Where(l => l.IdOrcamento == id).ToList();

        lista.ForEach(f =>
        {
            f.FlagLiberacao = 0;
            f.AutorizouReceberAtrazado = value;
        });

        contexto.SaveChanges();

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

> Quando eu for fazer o meu update(verbo put) eu preciso carregar todas
>   as propriedade ou apenas a que eu vou atualizar?

Nao, voce pode carregar somento o que voce vai usar.

```
[Route("atualiza/{id}/{value1}/{value2}")]
        public void AtualizaLiberacao(int value1, float value2, int id)
        {
            var lista = contexto.Liberacoes
                .Where(l => l.IdOrcamento == id)
                .Select(s =>
                {
                    s.AutorizouReceberAtrazado = value2,
                    s.FlagLiberacao = value1
                });
        }
```

> Tem como passar dois parâmetros pela URL, ao invés de apenas o id?

Sim voce pode passar quantos paramentros voce quiser.
exemplo: `[Route("atualiza/{id}/{value}")]`

Isso?

Comment: Tá dando esse erro: **Os argumentos de tipo do método "Queryable.Select<TSource, TResult>(IQueryable<TSource>, 
Expression<Func<TSource, TResult>>)" não podem ser inferidos com base no uso. Tente especificar explicitamente os argumentos de tipo. 
AutorizadorService C:\Projetos\AutorizadorService\AutorizadorService\Models\ItensLiberacao.cs** no select da lambda

Comment: coloca um breakpoint no var= lista... e confere se os paramentros tem alguma informacao

Comment: Não roda, tá dando pau exatamente no select da lambda. Nem compila. Tirei o var lista, pois não é necessário, pois o método é um void, e mesmo assim continua com pau.

Comment: @pnet você precisa trazer o objeto e mudar somente os campos, isso que você está fazendo não funciona!

Comment: @VirgilioNovic, como assim? Como eu faço isso?

Comment: @pnet se está tentando alterar dados com `Select`? isso na funciona! é ai que está errando, se tem que trazer o objeto na integra, ou usar outra técnica para dar um update nesses campos.

Comment: Fiz uma edição e veja se é isso, @VirgilioNovic, que você diz? Se for isso, como fica o parâmetro id na rota? Para que ele vai servir?

Comment: @pnet não poxa como é que altera os dados de uma entidade no Entity framework, não é trazendo o objeto com assim `var a = db.Pessoa.Find(1);` e depois `a.Nome = "novo nome";` e depois `db.SaveChanges();`! o que você está fazendo é para trazer informações e não para salvar informações.

Comment: Entendi. Select seria mais para os verbos get ou não é isso? Eu quero mesmo é um update. Se não for Select, qual seria?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65591/discussion-between-virgilio-novic-and-pnet).

Comment: eu recomendo que voce veja isso: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/crud-operation-in-connected-scenario-entity-framework.aspx